# Django 2.0.3 uploading files by models.FileField()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am a beginner django developer. I am building my first serious application and I would like to use the mechanism of uploading files to the server. I have searched a large part of web, but I have not found an easy guide anywhere to deal with this issue in **django2**.

### Is there any experienced django ninja that could provide me with a comprehensive process to design this solution, from creating the model through the form and the apparently view? I tried to work with official documentation, but I can not help it.

I will be very grateful! :D

Comment: please check this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Comment: this tutorial works for me !!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know what gone wrong with documentation. You should be more specific when asking questions, that helps people who want to answer.
Let me try to answer your question.

You Model will simply contain an extra filefield like this

`class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.FileField(upload_to='your_location')`

Your form will 
Simply a model form which will contain this model name as **class Meta**

in the view part you will simply handle this as a post request but you have to add request.FILES
So it will be like

```
If request.method=='POST':
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Now let me come to the upload_to argument. You have to pass a string here. The file will be uploaded to that directory within media directory if the media root setup already done by you.

Comment: ok, but what about the parameters of the path to write the file. I tried to do it the way you showed it, but when I try to make migrations the console throws an error that the field models.FileField () does not have a default value. And as for the documentation, I tried to get some information from it, but I can not search in it well enough to learn something more detailed.

Comment: my_field = models.FileField(upload_to='your_location', null=True)  do this